# Nhibernate criteria for conjunction

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate

In NHibernate if we use **Disjunction** than we write-

```
criteria.SetResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DistinctRootEntity)
```

but if we have to use **Conjunction** than what property to use?

Comment: Maybe a bit irrelevant but Criteria is obsolete unless you have a good reason, you should go with QueryOver or linq